# increasing from a rank $n_0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have this exercise:

:Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence, and $(v_n)$ given by $v_n=u_{n+1}-u_n$ for all $n\in N$
and such that $\lim_{n\to+\infty} v_n=a\in R^*_+$

the two first questions are:

1. prove that $\exists n_0\in N, \forall n\geq n_0, v_n\geq a/2$
2. prove that $\forall n\geq n_0, u_n\geq \frac{a}{2}(n-n_0)+u_{n_0}$

I answer these two questions, but the last question is what is the nature of $(u_n)$

from the fist question I deduce that
$\exists n_0\in N, \forall n\geq n_0, u_{n+1}-u_n>0$

so $(u_n)$ is increasing from a rank $n_0$.

How the deduce that it is increasing for all n ?

thank you

Comment: What is a rang?

Comment: Are you sure it's increasing for all $n$? Since the hypotheses only concern the limit, can't you make arbitrary changes to any initial segment of values of $u_n$?

Comment: i don't know @Gerry Myerson, how to answer the question of what is the nature of $(u_n)$ I don't know if it is increasing  or not

Comment: Can't you produce examples that are increasing for all $n$, and also examples that are not, just by making changes to an initial segment?

Comment: No I don't know how to do @Gerry Myerson  I also don't know what I can do with the second question

Comment: Huh? There isn't any "how". You just do it: change the first few values of $u_n$ so it's increasing for all $n$. Or, change the first few values of $u_n$ so it isn't increasing for all $n$. Just make any change you want to the first few values of $u_n$; that won't affect the limit.

Comment: any limit of $u_n$ ? we don't know if it converge

Comment: You *do* know that $u_n$ increases without bound, you've deduced that from the 2nd question.

Comment: On the nature of $u_n$: Take any sequence $(v_n)$ which may or may not converge to any  $a.$ Let $u_1$ be any number. For each $n$ define $u_{n+1}$ from $u_n$ and from $v_n$ by $u_{n+1}=u_n+v_n.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\lim v_n = a > 0$, this sequence will eventually be in the ball $(a - a/3,a+a/3) > 0$ (take $\epsilon = a/3$), so for $n$ big enough, $v_n = u_{n+1} - u_{n} > 0$ and thus $u_n$ is strictly increasing from that $n$.

You can't conclude that the sequence is aways increasing, take $u_n$ to be the sequence $0,-1,0,1,2,3,4,...$, $v_n \to 1 > 0$ and yet $u_n$ decreases at $n = 0$.

Suppose $u_n$ converges, then it is Cauchy and in particular $v_n = u_{n+1} - u_n \to 0$, wich is not our case, then there is no convergence.

As an application, if we take $u_n$ to be the partial sum of a series, $v_n$ is its general term, then we can see that if $v_n$ converges to a non-zero number, the series diverges.

Comment: what about the convergence of $(u_n)$ can we find that $(u_n)$ is bounded from upper to deduce that it is a convergent sequence?

Comment: The example of $u_n$ I gave satisfy your hypothesis over $v_n \to a = 1 > 0$ and it is unbounded and not increasing for every $n$, so it proves falsehood of both claims.

Comment: so we can say anything, just increasing from a rank $n_0$?

Comment: from the second question we can deduce that it is unbounded from the rank n_0 so $\lim u_n=+\infty$ right?

Comment: The difference between consecutive terms of a convergent sequence (and more strongly, the diameter of the image of $u \vert_{n \geq a} $ as $a$ grows, see Cauchy sequences) goes to zero, but that is exactly $v_n \to 0$, as I've added on the answer. Since $u_n$ is increasing then yes, it goes to $\infty$.

Comment: So @NoraNour, if the answer is complete, can you close the question clicking on the check mark?